# WPF designer issues in VS 2012

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and I'm having problems in building a simple UI. When I place a button at a random position in the window it doesn't appear EXACTLY where it would appear in the designer. Why's that, there wasn't such problem with the Windows Forms designer, let's say.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean: http://s14.postimg.org/kjs0vvpqn/wpf.png

Isn't there a way to make the button appear exactly how it would appear in the designer?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. If I create the exact same markup the button is fully visible to me. Further, it is displayed **EXACTLY** where you placed it on the designer, there's just an issue with the container it's in because you can't see the entire button. Is there code behind this form? If so, I'm pretty sure that would be relevant.

Comment: The code-behind is just a simple onclick function, that's all. No further changes to the layout.

Comment: Download http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ and hover on your button with snoop running and shift +ctrl. Inspect button and its parent layout containers ActualWidth. Snoop would end up showing some parent probably clipping this button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place a button to have a WYSIWYG position, wrap it into a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx), rather than a grid or StackPanel. For grid or stackpanel, the position is controlled by HorizontalLayout, Margin, Padding etc., whereas for Canvas, you can set the top and left property directly.

Comment: It can't be reproduced, even with a `Grid`, this is not going to change anything.

Comment: There is a significat change now with Canvas, it's placed correctly. There's a problem only when I place the button in the bottom left corner for example - it's fully visible in the designer and partially hidden when I run the application.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, I hope you really understand the post, before you comment and downvote, please make sure you have a careful read on the question and answer. You can reproduce this for grid, there is no conflict with my answer! Please correct me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: I also noticed that when I drag the button to the bottom left corner the Canvas.Top property changes instead of Canvas.Bottom let's say. If I replace it with Canvas.Bottom=0 it appears OK, but with the Canvas.Top property things are not the same.

Comment: @David, note that the OP is still having trouble - even with the Canvas. There is something much different going wrong.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, this is natural, but now the OP's problem is a different one. Do you agree? This is not a good "excuse" to justify your downvote and your comment "It can't be reproduced, even with a Grid, this is not going to change anything." Your comment is for, rather than against my answer, I don't understand your logic totally.

Comment: @David, my point in fact was exactly that if it's not working with the `Grid` it's not going to work with the `Canvas`. The `Grid`, by default, spans the entire client width of the `Window`. That being the case, the `Canvas` isn't going to change the underlying problem the OP is facing. Whatever it is.